# Is there anyone who is both Alvar and Nayanar?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism, alwar

Nayanars are the devotees of Lord Shiva and Alvars are the devotees of Lord Vishnu.

Is there anyone who is both Alvar and Nayanar? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Alwars" refers to a very specific group of 12 ancient Vaishnava saints who wrote Tamil poetry about Vishnu, and similarly the term "Nayanars" refers to a very specific group of 63 ancient Shaivite saints who wrote Tamil poetry about Shiva.  So to answer your question as stated, we just need to look at the [list of 12 alwars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alvars#Place.2C_month_and_star_of_birth):

1. Poigai Alvar
2. Bhoothathalvar
3. Peyalvar
4. Thirumalisai Alvar
5. Nammalvar
6. Madhurakavi Alvar
7. King Kulasekhara Alvar
8. Periyalvar
9. Andal
10. Thondaradippodi Alvar
11. Thiruppaan Alvar
12. Thirumangai Alvar

And you can verify for yourself that none of these people is included in the [list of 63 Nayanars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nayanars#The_sixty-three_Nayanmars).

Now if you're asking whether there are devotees of both Vishnu and Shiva, then the answer is yes.  Adi Shankaracharya, who was not only a Shaivite philosopher but also someone considered by many to be an incarnation of Shiva himself, composed the famous Bhaja Govindam in praise of Vishnu.

And according to [this article](http://www.thehindu.com/2002/07/18/stories/2002071800100800.htm), the Nayanar Sambandar once asked Tirumangai Alwar to compose a poem in praise of the deity of the [Tadalan Vishnu temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazheesirama_Vinnagaram) in Sambandar's home town of Sirkazhi. Sambandar was so pleased with Tirumangai Alwar's poem that he gave him a trident as a gift.

Comment: Both Nayanars and Alvars are ardent devotees to Lord Siva and Vishnu respectively. My question is it possible to be an *ardent* devotee to both of them?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes, you can certainly be an ardent devotee of both; Adi Shankaracharya is a good example.  Just think about all he's done for Vishnu temples like Badrinath, and his composition of Bhaja Govindam.  But the terms Alwar and Nayanar don't just refer to ardent devotees in general, they refer to very specific sets of people.

Comment: what makes Nayanars and Alvars different from ardent devotees?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Well, for one thing, each of the Alwars was an incarnation of either an associate of Vishnu (like Garuda or Vishwaksena) or an attribute of Vishnu (like the Sudarshana Chakra or the Sharanga bow).

Comment: Then what about Nayanars?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Well, the Nayanars constitute a more or less arbitrary list of 63 individuals who were instrumental in popularizing Shaivism in South India, just like the 12 Alvars popularized Vaishnavism in South India.  The Alwars and Nayanars were both part of the broader Bhakti movement in South India: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhakti_movement

Comment: There were also Siva Para bhaktas at the time of Nayanars but why aren't they called Nayanars, though they also have extreme love towards Siva? - Thank you.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Because the term Nayanar doesn't just refer to anyone who had extreme Bhakti for Shiva.  It refers to the specific people who were responsible in popularizing Shaivism in South India through their poetry (just as the Alwars' poetry popularized Vaishnavism in South India).

Comment: But I don't think the Bhakta Kannappa nayanar is a poet nor most of them.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yeah, some of them were responsible for the spreading of Shaivism in South India in other ways, primarily by poems about their life story inspiring people to become Shaivites.

Comment: Yes, but still there were also people who didn't spread it through poems, but their lives has been stories that inspired a lot to become Shaivities. My doubt is other Siva para bhaktas also might have inspiring stories because of their extreme love, but why aren't they Nayanars? Does Nayanars have more love than Para bhaktas do?

Comment: @JavaTechnical No, Nayanars didn't necessarily have more Bhakti than other Shiva bhaktas.  And the question is not who inspired people living today to worship Shiva,the question is who inspired the people in that era to become Shaivites.  People compiled lists of Nayanars to identify those who led to the popularization of Shavism in South India.

Comment: Ok. Could you tell me what is the meaning of the term 'Nayanar' other than the general meaning? Is there any specific cause for using that term?

Comment: @JavaTechnical If you're asking the literal meaning of the word, it means "dog of Shiva".  But when we say "Nayanar", we're generally talking about the specific list of 63 people compiled by Nambiyandar Nambi to identify those who were responsible for the spreading of Shaivism in South India.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also try to answer my question http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/what-is-the-difference-between-bhakta-and-para-bhakta