# What is the difference between Bhakta and Para Bhakta?

Tags: worship, bhakti

I would like to know the difference between Bhakta and Para bhakta?

- Is there any difference in how they worship?
- Is there any difference in their character?
- Do they do more Poojas than bhaktas?

Comment: Para Bhakti just means "ultimate devotion".  So the difference between a Bhakta and a Para Bhakta is a difference in the amount of devotion.

Comment: Is there any change in character of bkatas and para bhaktas also do para bhaktas do more poojas?

Comment: Well, different bhaktas express their devotion in different ways.  Some do it through pujas (although that's a newer custom), some do it through meditation, some do it through composing poetry, etc.  So it's hard to make a generalization.

Comment: I think to explain this would be harder than to give examples of people in our History who are known to be Para Bhaktas. Meerabhai, Hanuman, Tulsidas, Sri Ramakrishna, Sri Krishna Chaitanya, Tyagaraja, etc. are some bhaktas who are widely regarded as supreme devotion or para bhakti. So is there a difference in their character? Simply speaking YES. They are guile-less. They seek no return from God. They pray to God out of the Love that fills their heart. Not a moment passes in time that they are not thinking about God. Every mention of their Deva brings bliss and fills their soul with happiness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *bhakta* (devotee) is someone who does *bhakti* (devotion). The word *bhakti* has been derived from the Sanskrit root *bhaj*, which means to chant, sing or glorify.  So generally, a *bhakta* is someone who sings, chants or praises someone else or God through various means. But the thing is, the reason why a person does *bhakti* can be different and  this reason and attitude differentiates a *bhakta* from a *para bhakta* (a superior devotee).

The Gita says there are four kinds of people who do devotion:

> *catur-vidha bhajante mam janah sukrtino 'rjuna
>
>   arto jijnasur artharthi jnani ca bharatarsabha* [BG - 7.16]
>
> **Meaning**
>   O best among the Bharatas [Arjuna], four kinds of pious men render devotional service unto Me--the distressed, the desirer of wealth, the inquisitive, and he who is searching for knowledge of the Absolute.

So these are normal devotees because they worship God for the fulfilment of their own purpose and desires. But that devotion which is done out of love for God and without any personal desires is called as *uttama* or the best devotion:

> *anyabhilasita-sunyam jnana-karmady-anavrtam
>
>    anukulyena krsnanu-silanam bhaktir uttama* [BRS - 1.1.11]
>
> **Meaning**
>   Devoid of any personal desires, not tainted with impersonal knowledge and fruitive actions, following of Krishna in favour of Him is known as the best of all devotions.

So these kind of *bhaktas* who are devoid of personal desires are called as *niskama bhkata* and superior than the other devotees.

## Is there any difference in how they worship?

Because it is the attitude and mentality for doing devotion that is different, there are hardly any differences between how they worship. A devotee does the worship for fulfilling his personal desire, but a true devotee does this only to please his lord.

However, one important difference is that, mental worship (*manasika puja*) becomes the primary mode of worship for most such true devotees. And the *nabadha bhkati* (nine types of devotion: singing, chanting, remembering, etc.) remain common for most devotees.

## Is there any difference in their character?

Yes, as the feelings of devotion increases and one gets absorbed more and more in it, the character of the devotee changes and many other symptoms can appear. Their knowledge will mature and eventually they will understand and realize that everyone is nothing but God and their attitude towards other will change.

Generally there are people who are devoted to God, but because their knowledge is not mature their characters and attitude towards others are not good. Even they hate, despise or quarrel with others. So **there are these 3 types of devotees: ordinary or common devotee, intermediate devotee and best devotee:**

1. Ordinary Devotee

   > *arcāyām eva haraye pūjāṁ yaḥ śraddhayehate
   >
   >   na tad-bhakteṣu cānyeṣu sa bhaktaḥ prākṛtaḥ smṛtaḥ* [SB - 11.2.47]
   >
   > **Meaning**
   >   He is considered as an ordinary devotee who faithfully worships the Lord and his *acharya* or guru, but doesn’t respect other devotees and other people.

   This is the beginning stage of a true devotee. He likes his personal deity whether it's Vishnu, Shiva, Krishna or anyone else and he likes his guru or *acharya*. But he has negative feelings for devotees of other sects and traditions. In this stage the ego is very high so it causes the feeling of personal superiority and produces negative feelings towards others.
2. Intermediate Devotee

   > *īśvare tad-adhīneṣu bāliśeṣu dviṣatsu ca
   >
   >   prema-maitrī-kṛpopekṣā yaḥ karoti sa madhyamaḥ* [SB - 11.2.46]
   >
   > **Meaning**
   >   An intermediate devotee loves the Lord and is friendly to all devotees of lord. He shows mercy to ignorant people but disregards those who dislike the Lord.

   This generally happens because a devotee considers himself and other devotees fortunate and superior because they are walking on the path of God and not following materialistic life. So a subtle ego in him causes to dislike other materialistic people. (In this state there is *dvesha* towards the materialistic world)
3. Best Devotee

   > *sarvabhūteṣu yaḥ paśyedbhagavadbhāvamātmanaḥ
   >
   >   bhūtāni bhagavatyātmanyeṣa bhāgavatottamaḥ* [SB - 11.2.45]
   >
   > **Meaning**
   >   He is best devotee who sees his own self situated in everything and sees everything situated in God.

   This is the state when a devotee actually realizes everything is God (*vasudeva sarvam iti*). There is neither *raga* (attachment or liking) nor *dvesha* (dislike or hatred) for anything. Generally devotees say everything is God, in everyone God resides, etc., but they don't actually realize it. When they do, they become the best devotees.

## Do they do more puja than bhaktas?

Well, it's not like that. But just like Sai has mentioned in [his comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3214/what-is-the-difference-between-bhakta-and-para-bhakta#comment5799_3214) they always remember their Lord. Even a moment feels like an aeon to them without their Lord. It's a thing of inner mentality, not external worships. But because true devotion is generally love, no one can say how it will manifest. People do different sorts of things out of love. So depending upon one's personality, attitude and knowledge a *bhakta* can do anything out of devotion, even may perform more *pujas*, *vratas*, etc.

---

## Update

True devotion is that which is causeless and without any personal desires. To state this I cited a verse from Bhakti Rasamruta Sindhu which sums it all beautifully in one verse. BRS is one of the best books that exists on devotion. But if you are somehow biased by sectarian views and don't appreciate works and writings of other saints, even if they are correct, then kindly ignore that verse (BRS - 1.1.11) and consider the following from Narada Bhakti Sutra instead:

> *gunarahitam kamanarahitam pratikshanavardhamanam* [NBS - 54]
>   - True devotion is devoid of material qualities and desires and it increases every moment.

If NBS is also controversial to you then please ignore that as well and replace it with the following verses from Bhagavata which also states the same thing:

> *ahaituky apratihatā yayātmā suprasīdati* [SB - 1.2.6]
>   *ahaituky avyavahitā yā bhaktiḥ puruṣottame* [SB - 3.29.12]
>   -Such devotional service must be unmotivated and uninterrupted...

*PS: I am neither a Gaudiya Vaishnava nor do I belong to any sect or sampradaya. I respect all saints so I don't think a right and correct thing is controversial just because a saint from another sect says it.*

Comment: The Bhakti-rasamrita-sindhu is a somewhat controversial thing to site.  Its doctrines are mostly accepted only by Gaudiya Vaishnavas.

Comment: You said the best devotees has neither likes nor dislikes? But in which cadre does a devotee fall if he treats every one equal, and sees god in everything and he still have passion towards his work and love towards his family members and wife?

Comment: @JavaTechnical sorry for replying late as I was away. If he sees god in everything and has passion towards work and family, but **no attachments** , then the *bhakta* becomes a *jnani*.

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between having attachment and having passion on work and family?

Comment: @JavaTechnical One has attachment for his work or family when he has expectations from it and the mind cannot stop thinking about it. If work or family causes disappointment or joy from time to time, then the mind is attached. Having passion means, one likes what he is doing but has no expectations from it. Irrespective of profit or loss, good or bad, he will do it. He does things out of duty not out of desire; he likes what he does but stays unaffected by the outcomes.

Comment: Thank you. But how can we get passion, when we don't expect something for that? Also, what are pure desires?

Comment: @JavaTechnical yes, that's the tricky thing and for which only there are so many paths and practices. Certainly one would do something only out of some form of desire to get something in return, but to keep the mind unaffected by the results is the real thing. Actions should be done with the sense of duty, pls see BG 2.38. To like something and yet remain unattached to it is indeed difficult, but that's the way it should be. Karma Yoga, Bhakti Yoga, Jnana Yoga, etc. are paths that help one to achieve that state.

Comment: @JavaTechnical i am not sure about pure desires because desire in any form is tainted by nature. So *bhkati* should be *nishkama* or without any desires. However, it should be without any personal desires, desires related to God has to be there. It's hard to become desire-less, so desires are diverted towards God and others. May be that's what you are referring as pure desire where there are no personal motives.

Comment: @jabahar Also what is the difference passion and love? Love also expects nothing in return. Also, but Lord Krishna says to be dispassionate? Why? We aren't actually seeking for any desires? Why do we need to be dispassionate to them?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Lord Krishna says to be dispassionate towards material things and relations, but not for Him. Passion and love towards God is liberating, but passion and love towards material things and beings is only but binding. May be we can chat sometime so we can talk more, please feel free to leave me a message...

Comment: @jabahar Ok now let us move this discussion to chat

Comment: @JavaTechnical I am in chat now...ping me..

Answer (score 1):

Vivekananda quoting Narada says that Bhakti is "intense love of God". He further states "The repetition of names, the rituals, the forms, and the symbols, all these various things are for the purification of the soul. The greatest purifier among all such things, a purifier without which no one can enter the regions of this higher devotion (Para-Bhakti), is renunciation...This is religion - renunciation." (C.W., V3, p 70)

When one has attained Para-Bhakti, all thought of this world falls off, one whole mind and soul are devoted to God only. Outer manifestations of rituals may or may not fall off. Vivekananda once asked Pavhari Baba (whom he considered to have attained the highest states of Para-Bhakti) why he performed ritualistic Karmas and ritualistic worship of Shri Raghunathji. Pavhari Baba replied "'Why do you take for granted that everybody makes Karma for their own good? Cannot one perform Karma for others?'" (C.W. V4, p.293)

Religion lies not in rituals, religion lies in realization. Realization is gained through renunciation.

Comment: What is performing karmas for others mean?

Comment: Pavhari Baba continued to do ritualistic worship even though he was a realized soul. He had no need to do ritualistic work for his own good. The karma that was coming from his continued ritualistic worship he was doing for the benefit of others.

Comment: Then what if one does ritualistic worship, for the sake of none (neither for himself nor for others)? What is it called?

Comment: @JavaTechnical It is called karma yoga.